# strptime() argument 1 must be string, not type Django

Tags: python, django, validation, date, strptime

I'm having trouble figuring out where I went wrong with this app trying to validate that a date is either in the present or future. But I'm getting the error in question.
Here is the error:

```
class AppointmentManage(models.Manager):
    def appointvalidate(self,postData):
        errors={}
        pause=datetime.datetime.strptime(time,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
        if len(postData['task'])<2:
            errors["Task field cannot be left blank"]="task"
        if len(postData['task'])<20:
            errors["Task field is too long"]="task"
        if len(postData['date'])<1:
            errors["Date field cannot be left blank"]="date"
        else:
            print "this is pause "
            print pause
        if pause<datetime.datetime.now():
                errors["Only present and future dates are permissable"]="date"
        if len(postData['time'])<1:
            errors["Time field cannot be left blank"]="time"
        return errors
```

Comment: What is `time`?

Comment: did u just use a reserved python name `time` for the name of the variable?

Comment: Anyway, code like this doesn't belong in a Manager class. It either goes in a validator or in a clean_<field> method on a form.

Comment: Yep, I figured it out before I came back to look at this. Sorry to have wasted your time .Thank you .

Comment: so what the error was? :)

Comment: I can't even remember. I've run into more errors than I can count.